# Replace a string matched by certain regexp with its length in Vim

Tags: regex, vim

In Vim, how do I replace a string matched by certain regexp with its length, like this:

> Regexp = "\w*"
>
> "hello" -> "5"
> "bye" -> "3"

Is it possible to do it with :s or do I need to write some script?

Best regards

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Replace 'hello' with your regex expression and this should work in VIM:

```
:s/hello/\=strlen(submatch(0))/
```

Comment: Thanks, I didn't know about \= before

Comment: I had to grep the docs to figure out what this is: `:h sub-replace-expression`